# What is a better way to write this function?

Tags: functions

```lisp
(cl-defun filename-from-buffer (&key get-ext get-path)
  (let ((filename (buffer-name))
        (pathname (buffer-file-name)))
    (setq ret (car (split-string filename "\\.")))
    (when get-path
      (setq ret (car (split-string pathname "\\."))))
    (when get-ext
      (setq ret filename))
    (when (and get-ext get-path)
      (setq ret pathname))
    ret))
```

I am fairly new to Emacs and Lisp (eLisp) and I wanted a function that would return the name of the file which is open in the current buffer. The function should take some optional arguments determining whether we want the full path, the extension or just the sole name of the file.

I feel like my implementation is pretty naive and it depends on the order of lines as well because I could not figure out how to do an `if-else` chain and return within. So is there a more elegant/more secure or just a better way to do this? By better, I mean something that uses the functionality of language which is already provided, an implementation that does not depend on the order of cases and/or something that does branching in a better way.

Comment: There are functions for all your aims: `file-name-nondirectory`, `file-name-sans-extension`, `file-name-extension`. If-else-statement: `(if PREDICATE IF-BRANCH ELSE-BRANCH)` where `PREDICATE` `IF-BRANCH` and `ELSE-BRANCH` are expressions. You can also use [`(cond (EXPR FORM) ...)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Conditionals.html).

Comment: `buffer-name` often contains the base file name, but not always.  You want to use `(file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name)` instead.  Also the GNU convention is to only use "path" for lists of directories, like `load-path`, and to use "file name" otherwise, including for fully qualified absolute file names.

Comment: The question is too broad or primarily opinion-based, so it risks being closed. This site is about specific Q&A, not general what-is-better discussion or requests for advice. Maybe try a discussion site such as Reddit for such a question.

Comment: It is a bad idea to `setq` `ret` without locally binding it in a `let`. Because it changes the global variable `ret` (if there is one). Reason is: Emacs uses dynamic extend for variables by default. Second: emacs provides portable functions to extract parts of the filename `file-name-...`, your code wouldn't work with unixes.

Comment: @jue what do you mean, "without binding it in a `let`". I have bound it inside the `(let (...) (setq ret))` block. Do you mean I should do it like this: `(let ((ret nil)) (setq ret "value"))`?

Comment: @scribe yes this is what I meant. Have a read at the first chapters of the book [Let-over-Lambda](https://letoverlambda.com/textmode.cl/guest/chap3.html#sec_4). It is about Common Lisp, but you will get a better understanding. (there might be easier to digest explanations, though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cond`, which corresponds to "if"-"else if"-"else" chains in other languages.  It picks the first clause whose condition is non-`nil`.

Here we don't need a temporary variable, since we're just going to return the value from the `cond` clauses directly.  The last clause has `t`, the "true" value in Lisp, as its condition, so it will be picked if none of the preceding clauses were picked.

```
(cl-defun filename-from-buffer (&key get-ext get-path)
  (let ((filename (buffer-name))
        (pathname (buffer-file-name)))
    (cond
     ((and get-ext get-path)
      pathname)
     (get-path
      (file-name-sans-extension pathname))
     (get-ext
      filename)
     (t
      (file-name-sans-extension filename)))))
```

---

Emacs Lisp also has `if`, but you only get an "if" clause and an "else" clause, no "else if":

```
(if some-condition
    value-if-true
  value-if-false)
```

Though you could achieve that by nesting several `if`s in each other, it's more elegant to use `cond` in such a situation.  Nested `if`s would look like this:

```
(if (and get-ext get-path)
    pathname
  (if get-path
      (file-name-sans-extension pathname)
    (if get-ext
        (file-name-extension filename)
      (file-name-sans-extension filename))))
```